# Jquery ajax - Make a function wait till the previous function gets executed

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-ajaxq

When the user clicks the Submit button, i am making a Jquery AJAX call to check if the user is an Admin User or not, if the User is a Admin i am showing a Information popup for the user with OK button.. Once the user clicks the OK button the form can be submitted.. If the user is not an Admin user then the form can be submitted.

Below is sample code

```
function btnFormSubmit()
{
   SubmitForm()
}

function SubmitForm()
{
IsUserAdmin();
SubmitForm();
}


function IsUserAdmin()
{
var userName = $('#txtUser').val();
           $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: admin/checkisAdmin,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                "userId": userName
                },
             success: function (data) {
             if(data * 1){
              showAdminPopup();
             }
           else
           {
           }           
          },
error : function () {
}
});
}

function showAdminPopup() 
{
 var dlg = $("#divAdminDialog");
        dlg.dialog({                   
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        create: function(e, ui) {

            },
        buttons: [{
             id: "ok_id",
             text: "OK",
             click: function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
           }
          }]
        });
      }
```

The issue with the above is the IsUserAdmin() completes execution and shows the Popup and before the User clicks on OK button the SubmitForm() is executing and form is getting submitted

Comment: That seems to be a weird way to check for admin. Would you not already know at the time of login that a user has admin, or not, and avoid such handling?

Comment: @PaulT. as i cannot post my actual business scenario as it is confidential i said Admin, my scenario is on the click of a button i will make a ajax call and check for a condition and that returns true or false, if it is true then i will show a popup and when the user clicks ok proceed with form submit.. if it is false the proceed with the form submit without any popup.

Comment: I don't need to know your "business scenario", my previous comment was meant as alternative idea/thought. Well, you could possibly add `async: false` to your ajax parameters, but I would NOT use that approach. I would avoid using ajax for checking if a user has admin since that can be determined at login, but whatever.